# directx error - lnk2011

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, directx

I've link all the necessary directx lib  and include the .h files and still i got those error :

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DirectDrawCreate@12
1>Sound.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__mmioRead@12
1>Sound.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__mmioOpenA@12
1>Sound.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__mmioClose@8
1>Sound.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__mmioAdvance@12
1>Sound.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__mmioAscend@12
1>Sound.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__mmioSetInfo@12
1>Sound.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__mmioDescend@16
1>Sound.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__mmioGetInfo@12
```

those error are because the directx, i've tried all the solutions and it not help
i'm using visual studio 2010 on xp .
i hope someone know how to fix this.

thanks
shir

Comment: I've edit the question

Comment: See [Whither DirectDraw?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/06/16/wither-directdraw.aspx). ``DDRAW.LIB`` is no more but you can still use legacy DirectDraw if you really need to.

Comment: The mmio functions are in ``winmm.lib``. These APIs were never in the DirectX SDK, only the Windows SDK. They also date back to Windows 3.1, so they are ancient.